# How to resolve java.util.Map as a paramter of @RestController method in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, http-request-parameters

I have method in like below:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping("/test/map")
    public void testMap(@RequestParam String params, @RequestParam List<String> list, @RequestParam(name = "map") Map<String, String> map) {

        System.out.println("map >>> " + map);
        System.out.println("params >>> " + params);
        System.out.println("list >>> " + list);
    }

}
```

I send request with url: `https://localhost:8080/test/map?params=stringParam&list=va1,val2,val3&map=param1:val1,param2:val2` and I get an error:

```
org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map'
```

There is a way to resolve java.util.Map as a single parameter?

I tried to modify url but with no results.

Comment: You could use a CustomConverter for that: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-type-conversions#creating-a-custom-converter

Comment: I wonder there is a way to use some standard spring boot converter?